# Can we track the errorlogs for the TriggerSends in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: triggers, salesforce-marketing-cloud, exacttarget

We have created few TriggerSends to send out an email to customers via API and if something got errored out how can we track those details?

Comment: You'll get a lot more eyes on your SFMC questions over at [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com), specifically with the [marketing-cloud](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing-cloud) tag.

Comment: You'll need to be more specific than "something got errored out".  Did the API call fail? Did the queue pile up?  Which API?  TXM or traditional?  There are multiple points of potential failure in the triggered send flow.